# Java: How to build a scalable Job processing mechanism

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency

I need to build a job processing module wherein the incoming rate of jobs is in the order of millions. I have a multiprocessor machine to run these jobs on. In my current solution for [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/index.html#java), I use Java's [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) framework to create a job queue, a LinkedListBlockingQueue, and the number of threads equals the available processor on the system. This design is not able to sustain the incoming rate as the job queue keeps growing and within seconds it reports the overflow even though the CPU utilization is not maxed out. The CPU utilization remains somewhere in the range of 30-40 percent.

It means that most of the time is going away in thread contention where other CPU remains idle. Is there any better way of processing the jobs so that CPUs are utilized better so that job queue does not overflow?

Comment: Since your pc utilization is so low suggesting that there is more processing bandwith.. maybe increasing the number of threads will help in your case. Athough analysing your jobs could give a beeter ideas as to how many threads are needed. The more time threads spend waiting on each other, the more threads you can create to utilize unused processing power. However if you crash within seconds, even this wont help. Maybe you need more computers to distribute the jobs to?

Comment: No, the threads are waiting on the queue to take job sequentially which holds a lock so while one thread calls a queue.take(), the other threads wait. I thought introducing more threads will only worsen the situation since each thread will have to wait. Probably more threads could help if the job processing time was more and each job was doing some I/O, right?

Comment: for such a heavy load, even if you design highly efficient executor, chances are the incoming rate become too high and all available memory would be eaten by the job queue. To avoid it, use ArrayBlockingQueue with fixed or limited capacity. It also saves memory for links compared to LinkedBlockingQueue.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at [Disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor) first.  This provides a high performance in memory ring buffer.  This works best if you can slow the producer(s) if the consumers cannot keep up.

If you need a persisted or unbounded queue I suggest using [Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) (which I wrote)  This has  the advantage that the producer is not slowed by the producer (and the queue is entirely off heap)

Both of these are designed to handle millions of messages per second.

Comment: "producer is not slowed by the producer"? I feel there is a consumer missing there somewhere ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hi You could use a queuing system like RabbitMQ to hold messages for processing. If you combine this with Spring AMQP you can have easy (one line of config) multi-threading and the messages would be stored on disk until they are ready to be processed by your application.

Comment: Can you add a comment about what throughputs this solution would be suitable for?

Comment: We've used queuing for anything for several 1000 transactions per day to a million+ per day. AMQP/JMS isn't without it's drawbacks obviously. I feel it provides a lot out of the box and simplifies your code because managing job queues is taken out of your application. I am not saying it's the right way but maybe an option the OP would like to explore.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is probably wrong. If the CPU was busy switching jobs, then the CPU utilization would be 100% - anything that the CPU does for a process counts.

My guess is that you have I/O where you could run more jobs. Try to run 4 or 8 times as many threads as you have CPU cores.

If that turns out to be too slow, use a framework like [Akka which can process 10 million messages in 23 seconds without any special tuning](http://www.akkaessentials.in/2012/03/processing-10-million-messages-with.html).

If that's not enough, then look at [Disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor).

Comment: well, yeah that makes sense. I mean i don't remember checking at each CPU utilization, i mean the overall multiprocessor CPU usages were hovering somewhere around 30-40 percent. let me go back and check if there was any single CPU busy doing all the switching and getting maxed out..

Comment: I will also check the performance after increasing the number of threads.

Comment: Increasing the number of threads actually increased the CPU usage. thanks everyone for responding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Magical libraries are very tempting but often mislead you to wrong direction and makes your solution day by day more complex...Disruptor people LMAX says this too :) .. I think you should take a step back and understand the root cause of Job queue depth. In your case looks to me its same type of consumers so i don't think disruptor is going to help. 
You mentioned about thread contention. 
I would suggest first try to see if you can reduce the contention. Not sure if all your jobs are related but if not may be can use some portioning technique of queue and reduce unrelated jobs contention. Then you need to know why your consumers are slow. Can you improve your locking strategy by using ReadWrite locks or NonBlocking collections in consumers.